# Cocoa: Adding a subview to a view from a different class and nib

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nib

If i have two nibs with several views, is there a way for me to use the addSubview: method between them? What I would like to do is take a view from one of the nibs and tell it to add a subview that would be a view in the other nib file.

The reason I have them in separate nibs is because the subview from the second nib will be added several times, using the same template but different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a view in one nib as a subview to the view in another nib.

You need to create a NSViewController object which will own the child nib. So that as soon as you initialize the view controller the nib associated with it is loaded. Now you can use the view property of the controller and add it as a subview to any other view.

The code below will help you understand better:

**YourViewController.m**

```
-(id)init 
{    
    self = [super init];

     if(nil != self)
     {
         [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myNibName" owner:self];
     }

     return self; 
}
```

**YourOtherClass.m**

```
-(void)addYourViewControllerViewAsSubview
{ 

    YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];

    [yourOtherViewOutlet addSubview:yvc.view];

}
```